# print column value based on column name match in awk/sed

Tags: sed, awk

In my shell script after executing a few commands, I'm getting the output below:

```
Name      English    Maths    science   Social studies
------    --------  --------  -------- ---------------
James     20        25        30        40

(many values)
(or)

Roll Num   Name     English   Maths   science   Social studies
---------  ----    --------  -------  --------  ---------------
  1        James     20        25        30        40

(Many values)
```

I want to print the values based on a column heading match.

```
Example:
cmd(matching Maths) test.txt

o/p:25
```

I have tried few `awk` and `sed` commands,But I didn't get proper output.

Can someone help me how to get this?

Comment: @don_crissti If i'm getting duplicate values also fine.Just i want print the values based on a column heading match.

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk -v subj="Maths" '{
    for(n=1;n<=NF;n++){
      if ($n==subj){
        subp=n;nrr=NR+2
   }};
   if(NR==nrr){
      print $subp
   }}' test.txt
```

Here if subject is `Maths` the field position `subp` and `nrr` (`NR +2` where the value for the `subj` `Maths` lies) is assigned.